# Why does onMapLongClick throw a RuntimeException?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to implement `OnMapLongClickListener` to my map application so that whenever a user long-clicks on the screen, a marker appears in the corresponding location.

My MainActivity class is as follows:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
      mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Hatfield and move the camera
        LatLng hatfield = new LatLng(51.7471060, -0.22978);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(hatfield)
                .title("Hertfordshire Times")
                .snippet("Hertfordshire Lecturer wins Nobel Prize")
                .draggable(true));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(hatfield));

        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(hatfield)
                .fillColor(0x5500ff00)
                .strokeColor(Color.WHITE).radius(60));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng latLng) {
        if(mMap != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Long press", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("You placed a marker here")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker()));
        }
    }
}
```

Once the `OnMapLongClick` method runs, it throws a `NullPointerException` (a snippet of the error is shown below):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void     com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$OnMapLongClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                           at com.example.paulmbw.map_application_fyp.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:29)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I have seen similar answers on Stack but cannot seem to find a solution for my problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Because `mMap` is **NULL**

Comment: Move `mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);` to the `onMapReady()` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: that worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Call `mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);` inside `onMapReady()`.

`mMap` is `null` when you're calling that on it because the statement right before it is an asynchronous one. It doesn't wait for your callback `onMapReady()` to get complete or anything like that. It calls it when its ready instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because `mMap` is **null** (not yet ready).

Move your listener in `onMapReady()` method.

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Hatfield and move the camera
        LatLng hatfield = new LatLng(51.7471060, -0.22978);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(hatfield)
                .title("Hertfordshire Times")
                .snippet("Hertfordshire Lecturer wins Nobel Prize")
                .draggable(true));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(hatfield));

        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(hatfield)
                .fillColor(0x5500ff00)
                .strokeColor(Color.WHITE).radius(60));

        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(MapsActivity.this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To Perform On Map Click

```
private GoogleMap map;
private Marker marker;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity) getActivity();
activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.select_location);
super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  Log.d("Map","On view created");
map = getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        Log.d("Map","Map clicked");
        marker.remove();
        drawMarker(point);
    }
});
```

You can see the more in detail For Google Map and Location Manager 
Visit : http://www.studygtu.com/2016/02/google-map-implement-and-location.html

Comment: This is a **bad** idea, and might not solve the problem -- 1) *getMap()* doesn't  guarantee to return a non-null object. -- 2) *getMap()* is deprecated.